# how to call my javascript function from within this specific context

Tags: javascript, razor

can anyone please tell me how to call the function GetDuration from within the following context:

```
@{
...
...
<div>  GetDuration(@item.StartDate, @item.EndDate) </div>
...
...
}
```

The function `GetDuration()` dynamically creates another DIV inside the parent DIV mentioned in my context.

I have 2 problems:

- I do not know how to call my function `GetDuration()` from the spot shown in the code
- `startdatum.Month.ToString("MMMM");` returns `"MMMM"` instead of the name of the month

Thanks in advance!

This is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function GetDuration(startdatum, einddatum) {
    var maand1 = startdatum.Month.ToString("MMMM");
    var maand2 = einddatum.Month.ToString("MMMM");
    var duration = "Date: ";
    if (maand1 == maand2) {
        duration += item.Startdate.Day.ToString()
            + " - " + item.Enddate.Day.ToString()
            + " " + maand1
            + " " + item.Startdate.Year.ToString();
    }
    else {
        duration += item.Startdate.Day.ToString()
            + item.Startdate.Month.ToString("MMMM")
            + " - " + item.Enddate.Day.ToString()
            + " " + item.Enddate.Month.ToString("MMMM")
            + " " + item.Startdate.Year.ToString();
    }
    var dynDiv = document.createElement("div");
    dynDiv.class = "HP_DateDiv";
    dynDiv.innerHTML = duration;
    document.body.appendChild(dynDiv);
}

</script>


    @{  string prevYear = "";

    foreach (var item in ViewData.Model) {

        string year = item.StartDate.Year.ToString();
        if (year != prevYear)
        {
            <div class="contentheader"> 
                @year Formula 1 Tickets
            </div>

            prevYear = year;  
        }
        <div class="HP_eventBodyDiv">
            <div class="HP_picDiv" style = "width:100px; height:100px;">
                <a href="http://www.cssdrive.com/" class="highlightit"><img  src="../../Content/Pics/auto.jpg" alt="oto" height="50" width="50"/></a>
            </div>
            <div class="HP_eventDiv">
                <div class="HP_eventNameDiv">@item.Name
            </div>
<!--This is the spot to call my function with something like "GetDuration(@item.StartDate, @item.EndDate)"-->
                <div class="HP_viewBuyBtnsDiv">
                    <input id="btn_View" type="button" value="View Event" class="contentbtn"/>
                    <input id="btn_Buy" type="button" value="Buy Tickets" class="contentbtn"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>            

        };
     }
```

Comment: Am I missing something? `GetDuration` does not look like JavaScript, and it's in a `text/javascript` script block...

Comment: Welcome to [SO]. Please take some time to read through the [faq]. It's generally appreciated if you take some additional time to make sure your post is well formatted and can be easily read.

Comment: `<div><script>GetDuration(@item.StartDate, @item.EndDate)</script></div>`?  What are the `@` for?

Comment: You can't mix JavaScript and HTML like that?  What are you doing?

Comment: what zzzzBov said. then specify what @{ stands for, my guess is for some server processing

Comment: Thats MVC.net Razor Syntax. you can't call java script like that at all.
All your scripting should be placed in the header tag. Use jQuery or manage the DOM from outside your HTML

Comment: wtf is this. never seen anything like it

Comment: @Blast_dan: What's MVC Razor?

Comment: Sorry, I'm busy in Visual Studio with C# creating a MVC Razor solution

Comment: it's essentially shorthand for asp code blocks `<%= ... %>`
http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/15/asp-net-mvc-3-razor-s-and-lt-text-gt-syntax.aspx

Comment: @Rocket to evaluate the variables item.StartDate and item.EndDate

Comment: @Ger: I don't know anything MVC Razor, so I didn't know what that was.

Comment: @Rocket :) don't worry...I'm just learning myself...........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to see if I can explain this a bit for you.
Razor Syntax allows us to do some great stuff like your doing on your view. The Ability to iterate through a collection on your view is really great, and can give some good flexibility to create dynamic pages.
They server is actually creating the Razor view with the syntax that your providing and then sends the build HTML page to the Client. That includes the script tags. So what your trying to do doesn't realty work. You can't iteratively call JavaScript Function in the @foreach Like that because the page hasn't been rendered yet.
You should only think of using Javascript once the Razor View has been completely formed. Then you can use JavaScript to edit the DOM.

So my suggestion is what the EDIT says. Let the sever calculate that property and send it with the Model.

EDIT:

Wait after looking at updated Code I think your going about this the wrong way. I Don't understand why you are using javascript to calculate your Duration. You should edit your model that you are passing through to contain the duration especially if its a calculated field like that. then you can just display the Duration just as any other property.

EDIT 2:

```
public class MyNewClass
{
public DateTime StartDate {get;set;}
public DateTime EndDate {get;set;}
public int Duration
{
get{
//Do your Logic Here with startdate and enddate
}
set;
}
}
```

Comment: sorry, I don't know what you mean. There already is a script tag at the top of my view, but the closing tag is somewhere in the middle and the i continue with the @{......CODE....}

Comment: yes, that is a possibility, but I thought his would be much nicer. I seem to be constantly updating all of my webservices for my needs, while i did deliberately tried to keep my webservices general. I never worked with jQuery before. Is that a possibility? Why can I call my function from for example a onclick-event, but not from within the DIV-content?

Comment: You can do an on-click because the on-click event wont be raised until all the elements are created. Your trying to call JavaScript before an elements have been created. Also for this you don't need to edit your service. Create a new Model on you Client that has the calculated Field and Map the WebService Object to the newly created Client Model.

Comment: But if I do it in a onclick event....................then I do have to CLICK before the script is being run..........OR am  I completely missing the point here??

Comment: Yeah I don't think im explaining myself right.
Razor Views never hit the client until all the iteration is completed.
JavaScript cannot be run until the data is available on the Client.
Therefore JavaScript Cannot be run during an iteration

Comment: I'm Confused haha. You had said that your onclick events were working. and yes they will always work.
I'm just saying that you can't iterativly call javascript functions because the view is not on the client yet.

Comment: ok thx, I will try to create a new model on my Client. Would you happen to have an example of that please?? Many thanks for your patience though!!!!

Comment: See the Edit to the Answer,
then when you get your WebService Model just Map the WebService Object to the new Model

Comment: thanks for your answer. I managed. Many thanks. I now have a new problem, but I'll open another Question for that. Kind Regards

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work
I'd recommend answering as well. People will be less likely to help when you have a 0% answer rate